# get groups whithout activity the last 3 mounth and the user (Owner) SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, sandbox, salesforce2salesforce, community

how we can get list of (group.Name , group.LastFeedModifiedDate, user.Name , User.Username
Form User & CollaborationGroup where group.OwnerId = user.Id And group.LastFeedModifiedDate <
courantDate() - 30 mounth )

i have problem, whith SOQL we can use JOIN

thx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) in SOQL Queries. Assuming you meant 3 months, i.e. 90 days

```
select id, Name, Owner.Name from CollaborationGroup where LastFeedModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90
```

If you wanted to filter on Owners too, add that to the where clause (ownerIds is a collection of UserIds you want to filter on)

```
select id, Name, Owner.Name from CollaborationGroup where LastFeedModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90 AND OwnerId IN :ownerIds
```

If you wanted to get the MemberIds, you can use :

```
select memberId from CollaborationGroupMember where CollaborationGroup.LastFeedModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90
```

OR

```
select Id, Name from User where Id IN (select memberId from CollaborationGroupMember where CollaborationGroup.LastFeedModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90)
```

Comment: hi @techtrekker,

Comment: @KhaledZero I've added to my answer

Comment: i want a query like this 
`Selecte User.name, User.Username, CollaborationGroup.Name, CollaborationGroup.lastFeedModifiedDate 
From User, CollaborationGroup
Where CollaborationGroup.LastFeedModidiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90`
bat whith SOQL we can not use the Join "Form User, CollaborationGroup" like in SQL So there is an auther solution? Thx.

Comment: I want get :
`User.Id
User.Userame
Goup.Name
Group.LastFeedModifiedDate`

thx

Answer (score 0):

groups whithout activity the last 3 mounth and the Username (Owner) SOQL

```
SELECT Owner.Username, LastFeedModifiedDate, Name, OwnerId 
FROM CollaborationGroup 
WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:90
```

Comment: Please add some description text to your answer.

Comment: @mastOr .......done!

Comment: That's pretty much the same as techtrekker's first SOQL, just filtering on a different date field.